# Trouble using Nsight Compute on Google Colab: 'command not found' error with ncu and installation script error with Nsight Compute

Tags: cuda, google-colaboratory, nsight

I am trying to use ncu on Colab, however when I type

```
ncu
/bin/bash: ncu: command not found
```

A few days ago this command was working fine, I am unsure if I am making some mistakes in the code or if it is a problem with colab.

And I cannot install Nsight because if I run this:

```
!chmod +x  /content/drive/MyDrive/ncu/nsight-compute-Linux-2023.1.0.16-32451174.run
!/content/drive/MyDrive/ncu/nsight-compute-Linux-2023.1.0.16-32451174.run  --confirm
```

It shows after the license it presents this error

```
The program './install-Linux.pl' returned an error code (1)
```

I cannot use nvprof because of this error (nvprof is no longer supported on new architecture)

```
======== Warning: Skipping profiling on device 0 since profiling is not supported on devices with compute capability 7.5 and higher.
                  Use NVIDIA Nsight Compute for GPU profiling and NVIDIA Nsight Systems for GPU tracing and CPU sampling.
                  Refer https://developer.nvidia.com/tools-overview for more details.
```

Comment: “ A few days ago this command was working fine” — Colab is a cloud service with a number of different hardware and software versions being provisioned. What you a got a few days ago and what you got now can be different

Comment: This is a valid point. Do you know of any methods to verify a prior the presence of ncu? Do you think the paid version could solve this issue?

Comment: No and No, as far as I am aware. Depending on the time of day, load and geographic location, you could be provisioned with a node with a number of different OS, CUDA and GPU combinations. Unlike AWS, google don't expose anything or provide any guarantees about what hardware and software stack you will get. Paid or free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instructions to install CUDA Toolkit 12.1 on Google Colab, which includes Nsight Compute:

1. Download and install CUDA 12.1 from NVIDIA's installer

```bash
! set -x \
&& cd $(mktemp -d) \
&& wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.1.0/local_installers/cuda_12.1.0_530.30.02_linux.run \
&& sudo sh cuda_12.1.0_530.30.02_linux.run --silent --toolkit \
&& rm cuda_12.1.0_530.30.02_linux.run
```

2. Add CUDA binaries folder to `PATH`

```py
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':/usr/local/cuda/bin/'
```

3. Run Nsight Compute!

```bash
! ncu --version
```

Feel free to clone my existing Google Colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s9emr6atuWjugbZ1yLG-Ee0pnhPwciJ1?usp=sharing)!